# Increment Value Every Hour with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello i am trying to implement cloud functions into my text based online game that im developing to learn firebase

lets say that a player bought an apple farm which produces 1 apple every hour.
so we created this path in db
farms/username/applefarm
produced:0

What i am trying to do is use cloud functions to increment that produced value by 1 for every applefarm every hour.

any ideas?